# buildroot and the linux-kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot

I am new to buildroot and embedded linux, I have once build the root on my laptop using the buildroot and it took like 20 to 30 minutes, I want to know what kernel is used in the buildroot and how can I change it e.g. if I want to use the kernel of the freebsd in buildroot, would that be possible ?

Regards

Comment: Did you read any documentation? Did you use `make menuconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

buildroot comes with default builds -depending on what board/target image for- you're using, for example if you want to use stm or raspberry pi you type > make raspberrypi3_defconfig and then you can use: make menuconfig > choose kernel and then what's suitable for you, but if you want a basic build you will already find a default kernel